# Storing and displaying string

Tags: java

I am making a project on musical instrument store. I don't know how to store and display the name of the instrument on the bill. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You might want to add some code that you have completed so far, because without that there is no way to help.

Comment: Um, a little more info and some context is needed for anyone to be of any help here.

Comment: Hey, Mr.J Woodchuck. I just want get the name of the instrument on the bill. For example, if someone is buying a guitar,  the name of it has to appear on the bill.  I could just ask the user to enter the name of the instrument, but I would be risking my marks by doing that.